# QT UI jerks while Animating in a multiThreaded application!

Tags: multithreading, qt

MultiThreading problem in QT Application.

I have a multiThreaded application the main UI Thread and the worker
Thread. I have set the UI Thread with TimeCriticalPriority and the
worker thread with the Normal Priority. So that my UI does not freeze
at any point of time.
But when i try to animate a screen for switching from one screen to
other screen I see jerks on the UI.

The problem here is, when the UI Thread is animating to switch the
screens, the platform switches from UI Thread to the Worker thread
resulting in jerks. How can i solve this issue ?

I suppose the following solutions might help me to resolve these
issues. But how do i implement the solution ?
1. Making the worker thread wait untill the animation in UI thread is finished.
  - how should i make the worker thread wait ?
2. Making the UI thread busy untill the animation gets over ?
 - how can i make the UI thread busy ? (possible work around
solution might be calling some recursive functions in UI Thread so it does
not switch to worker thread).

Is there any other way to switch the screens from left to right or
vise versa without usingQPropertyAnimation in QT?

Any suggestion/help on this is highly appriciated.

Can anyone please let me know the possible solutions for this ?

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards
Varun Jajee

Answer (score 0):

Instead of raising the priority of your UI thread, you might want to lower the priority of your worker thread(s) (e.g. to LowPriority or LowestPriority).  That way your worker threads won't take CPU cycles from away from other threads/processes that your program might be indirectly relying on (e.g. threads that the OS uses to track the mouse, or similar).  (it's also preferable to lower thread priorities than to raise them, since some OS's prevent non-root processes/threads from raising their priority)

Also you might want to see if there are any Mutexes that your UI thread locks that might also be locked by the worker thread.  If there are, these might be causing a [priority inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inversion) that results in your UI thread being blocked until the worker thread releases the mutex.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. I'm using Windows CE 6.0 OS, I'm sorry I had not specified this in my earlier post. As per your suggestion, I reduced the priority of worker thread to LowPriority and later to lowestPriority but this did not help. I'm still facing the same issue. I'm in the design phase of the application,As of now I'm not using Mutex.

Comment: Kindly let me know if I can try any other solution !